# jQuery Autocomplete, enter triggers another binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am using jqGrid and have inline editing with a textfield using jQuery autocomplete. My problem is that autocomplete binds my enter key (to the input element) to select an item in the autocompletion list of suggestions. This is all nice, however, my jqGrid has also bound my enter key to the table row, saving the row and exiting edit mode.

How can I stop the row binding? I want to keep it for the other cells in the row. I sort of want to sneak in a cancel on the event bubbling here...

/HW

Comment: I am interested in your solution if you ever came up with one.  I've got a similar situation.

Comment: I ended up turning of the enter=save functionality and instead I bound up and down keys to the input elements to save and move the focus to next or previous row.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used jQGrid before but this problem of yours seems more related to events and bubbling.  I presume you are interested in the select event of the jquery ui autocomplete.  You can stick a `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling up to the jQGrid.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      <....continue doing your thing here.....>
   }
});
```

I hope this helps.